# Linear regression optimization

Tags: optimization, parameter-estimation, linear-regression, singularity

I'm trying to solve the linear regression problem but I'm stuck and can't solve the question.
imagine you have below form
$$ Y = WX-\epsilon $$
and $\epsilon $ is from Gaussian distribution $\epsilon \sim  normal(0,\Sigma)$.
we define errors like below
$$ error = \sum \epsilon^2 = (WX-Y)^T(WX-Y)  $$
we know we have $W* = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$  $$$$
now we want to prove this

if we know E($\epsilon$) = 0 and var($\epsilon$) = $\Sigma$ then we can have new estimator $W*_{new} = (X^T\Sigma^-1X)^{-1} X^T\Sigma^{-1}Y$ equal to previous estimator iff there exist a nonsingular F that below condition holds
$$ \Sigma X = XF $$
but I can not prove statement mentioned above. help!!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: prove last paragraph iff we have $\Sigma X = XF $ and F is nonsingular then new W and the old one are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\Sigma X = XF$, then $X  = \Sigma X F^{-1}$. If you plug $\Sigma X F^{-1}$ in for $X$ in $W^*_{new} = (X^\top \Sigma^{-1} X)^{-1} X^\top \Sigma^{-1} Y$ you will arrive at the expression for $W^*$ after a lot of cancellations. This proves one direction of the "if and only if" statement.

Comment: yes it's true but what about the other direction?(that was the challenging part for me)